# Errors (Module 'app' is not available!)

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am new to AngularJS, trying to get familiar with the framework.

I am getting the two errors (probably the result of module not being loaded):

- Failed to instantiate module app
- Module 'app' is not available!

I have looked over it, I have not miss-spelled any thing. I don't know why I won't work. Been at it for a few hours, it is probably a simple issue.

```js
// guessingGameController.js

var app = angular.module('app');

function GuessingGameController($scope) {
  $scope.varifyGuess = function() {
    $scope.deviation = $scope.deviation - $scope.guess;
    $scope.numOfGuesses = $scope.numOfGuesses + 1;
  };

  $scope.initializeGame = function() {
    $scope.guess = null;
    $scope.randNum = Math.floor((Math.random(1000) + 1));
    $scope.deviation = null;
    $scope.numOfGuesses = null;
  };
  app.controller('GuessingGame', GuessingGameController);
}

// app.js - create module "app"

var app=angular.module('app', []);
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <script src="../node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/
       3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="app.js"></script>
  <script src="js/controllers/guessingGameController.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="GuessingGame">
    <h2>Guess the Number !</h2>
    <p class="well lead">Guess the computer generated random number between 1 and 1000.</p>
    <label>Your Guess: </label><input type="number" ng-model="guess" />
    <button ng-click="verifyGuess()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Verify</button>
    <button ng-click="initializeGame()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Restart</button>
    <p>
      <p ng-show="deviation<0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is higher.</p>
      <p ng-show="deviation>0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is lower.</p>
      <p ng-show="deviation===0" class="alert alert-success">Yes! That"s it.</p>
    </p>
    <p class="text-info">No of guesses : <span class="badge">{{noOfTries}}</span>
      <p>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 ways to use [`angular.module`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#angular.module-arguments), with either 1 or 2 arguments.

This references a module named "app" that is supposed to exist, and returns it *if it does*:

```
var app = angular.module('app');
```

This creates a module named "app" and returns it on success:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);
```

The second argument (the array), can contain a list of other modules that the new module depends on.

In your code, the first line tries to access a module that does not yet exist, and you get an error.

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

function GuessingGameController($scope) {
  $scope.numOfGuesses = 0;
  $scope.verifyGuess = function() {
    console.log($scope.deviation, $scope.guess)
    $scope.deviation = $scope.deviation - $scope.guess;
    $scope.numOfGuesses = $scope.numOfGuesses + 1;
  };

  $scope.initializeGame = function() {
    $scope.guess = null;
    $scope.randNum = Math.floor((Math.random(1000) + 1));
    console.log($scope.randNum);
    $scope.deviation = null;
    $scope.numOfGuesses = null;
  };

}

  app.controller('GuessingGame', GuessingGameController);
```

```html
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.7/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="app">
  <div class="container" ng-controller="GuessingGame">
    <h2>Guess the Number !</h2>
    <p class="well lead">Guess the computer generated random number between 1 and 1000.</p>
    <label>Your Guess: </label><input type="number" ng-model="guess" />
    <button ng-click="verifyGuess()" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Verify</button>
    <button ng-click="initializeGame()" class="btn btn-warning btn-sm">Restart</button>
    <div>
      <p ng-show="deviation<0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is higher.</p>
      <p ng-show="deviation>0" class="alert alert-warning">Your guess is lower.</p>
      <p ng-show="deviation===0" class="alert alert-success">Yes! That"s it.</p>
    </div>
    <p class="text-info">No of guesses : <span class="badge">{{numOfGuesses}}</span>
      </p>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: ...In your code, the first line tries to access a module that does not yet exist, and you get an error.
This line is in app.js, to register module with Angular
var app = angular.module('app', []);

This line is in guessingGameController.js, so that I can use the module “app” in this file
var app = angular.module('app');

Now that “app”is visible, I can now register the controller with Angular:
  app.controller('GuessingGame', GuessingGameController); 
I have used this before and it worked out, so I know this is not the problem

Comment: You have so many mistakes in your code... Look at my example where I fixed the ones I found so far...

Comment: Ok, found the problem. Thanks, for correcting the code.